# Reading Config File in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file named .env in my code directory
.env has different configs

```
Eg : username = "xyz"
     password = "abcd"
```

In my code directory I have a folder called scripts

Inside scripts I have a script named "control.py" which needs to read the config from .env

How can I achieve this?

The structure is something as below

```
/var/www/html/code/.env
/var/www/html/code/scripts/control.py
```

.env has all the config stuffs and control.py needs to read these config.

Comment: maybe keep config in different format like JSON, YAML. They have modules to read it.

Comment: I cant do that, the config is PHP file and needs to stay as it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading in environment variables from an environment file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216311/reading-in-environment-variables-from-an-environment-file)

Comment: if file looks like python's code then you could load it - `text = open(filename).read()` - and execute it  - `exec(text)`. But if it doesn't look like Python's code then you will have to manually find data in file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use decouple module for this purpose. You can do pip install python-decouple.