# Automatically loading environment variables in a Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I have a small Flask application which uses the [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) lib to load environment variables that I store in a file named `.env`. Everything works just fine, but I recently realized that I actually never call the `load_dotenv()` method, so I'm not sure how it can work. 
Just out of curiosity I tried to play around it a little bit:

- I removed even the import (`from dotenv import load_dotenv`) - Still works
- I renamed `.env` to `something_else.env` - Doesn't work
- I uninstalled `python-dotenv` with `pip` - Doesn't work

I'm using version `0.10.3` and I have read the docs but didn't find anything about automatic loading of environment variables.

Any idea on how it can be possible? I could take a look at the code of `python-dotenv` but I'm quite new to python and I wish to spend my time on something more useful, but this thing just bugs me.

Comment: Steps

1. Create a .env file and put your env variable and their value eg. KEY=fads89fdafds

2. Create config.py file with following content
`from dotenv import load_dotenv`
`load_dotenv()`

3. in your app.py

`import config`
`KEY = os.environ.get('KEY')`

they will be available in your code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flask uses `load_dotenv` by default. See the [source](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0c0b31a789f8bfeadcbcf49d1fb38a00624b3065/src/flask/app.py#L925)

Answer (score 1):

`python-dotenv` is one of the best to use for loading .env files in your flask application.

I used it for my flask application as:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
env_file_name = "local.env"
env_path = Path.cwd().joinpath(f"env/{env_file_name}")
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
```

After running `load_dotenv()` your application now has all the environment variable loaded from the .env file. So you can access them through conventional os.getenv("variable name")

```
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.getenv('EMAIL_USER')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
```

That is all you need to do. Cheers!

Comment: This worked for me. If the python file and .env file are in the same directory just use
`from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(".env")`

Answer (score -1):

> I uninstalled python-dotenv with pip - Doesn't work

`Flask` uses `python-dotenv` as an external dependency to dynamically load  `Environment Variables` from `dotenv` using a separate `.env` file usually located under the project root near to `.flaskenv` file.
Refer to:

- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/#optional-dependencies
- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#dotenv

> I removed even the import (from dotenv import load_dotenv) - Still works

since you have installed `python-dotenv` package you don't need to **explicitly** call `load_dotenv()`, `Flask` **expect by default** to locate / find `.env` and `.flaskenv` files under the root of your project. But when you decide for some reason to put `.env` file in some where in your project structure for e.g use an `instance folder` which usually used to store a sensitive data of your application like `.env`, configs, logs, sqlite3 database file .. then you have to explicitly indicate the path to the `.env` file to be loaded by the app like so:

```
[..]

def create_app(config_object):
    """Create a Flask application using the app factory pattern."""

    app = Flask(__name__)

    load_config(app, config_object)  # here

    [..]

    return app

def load_config(app, config_object):
    """Load configuration."""

    import os

    from dotenv import load_dotenv

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    dotenv_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'var/instance/.env')  # just an e.g

    if os.path.exists(dotenv_path):
        load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
    else:
        import sys
        print('".env" is missing.')
        sys.exit(1)

    app.config.from_object(config_object)

[..]
```

> I renamed .env to something_else.env - Doesn't work

`.env` is **THE name** for the file to store `Environment variables`, you have not to rename it.

> which will load environment variables from a file **named .env** in the current directory or any of its parents or from the path specificied

Refer to `python-dotenv` [doc](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)