# How to get and set environment variables from .env in Python?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I want to add some global environment variables in my Python project. My thought was to add a `.env` in my project directory and set up some variables as follows:

```
URL='https://example.dev/api'
AUTHORIZATION='Basic QWERTYUIO234ERTY89IOKXCVB'
```

In Python, how would I be able to access those variables in my project. Online I've seen seen `os.getenv('URL')`, where `os` is also imported, but this doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone know how I might be able to do this? I could also set up an `appSettings` file to contain these global variables. Alternatively, if there's a better practice to use for Python, could someone please share?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading in environment variables from an environment file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216311/reading-in-environment-variables-from-an-environment-file)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include the package `python-dotenv`. This is the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) for your reference.

For your case, you will need to do the following,

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # take environment variables from .env.

url = os.getenv('URL', 'default_url')
authorization = os.getenv('AUTHORIZATION', 'default_authorization')
```

Comment: You don't need this plus it puts a runtime dependency on something that may not be there when the project is run elsewhere.  assuming that .env is just being set for use in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to set the following setting in to point at the .env file:
python.envFile