# How do I derive values from database for .env variables?

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, mysql-python

I am building a virtual assistant for my uni project and need to derive values from MySQL database in Xampp for my env variables such a name, password and email.
How should I get values of my .env variables connected to the database?
Currently, the .env values are:

```
USER = NONE
EMAIL= NONE
PASSWORD = NONE
```

Comment: Please edit the question with enough detail to identify an adequate question. Make it clear what you mean by environment variables, and what you like to do with them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading in environment variables from an environment file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216311/reading-in-environment-variables-from-an-environment-file)