# How to retrieve environment variables from .env using built-in "os" module

Tags: python, environment-variables

How can I get my key in my `.env` file?

What's the problem in my code (macOS)? The `dotenv` works fine, but is it possible to use only the `os` module?

In the `.env`:

```
key = 123456
```

and in the `test.py`:

```py
import os

actual_key = os.getenv('key')

print(actual_key)
```

Finally the output in console was:

```
None
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.getenv('key')` looks for 'key' in **environmental variables**. By default key-value pairs that are in .env file are **not** loaded into environment variables. If you want to load key this way you have to first add the contents of .env file to environment variables. I suggest using [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv) library:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv() # will search for .env file in local folder and load variables 

KEY_VAR = os.getenv('KEY')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dotenv` to load the environment variables from a `.env` file, like so:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load the environment variables from the .env file
load_dotenv()

actual_key = os.getenv('key')
print(actual_key)
```

`dotenv` can be installed with `pip install python-dotenv`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want. The `os.getenv` cannot get variables straight from the `.env` file.
TLDR;

Regarding the setting of the env vars:

In macOS to set the env var temporarily:

```bash
export [variable_name]=[variable_value]
```

To do it permanently:

- open `~/.bash-profile`
- scroll down to the end of the .bash_profile file
- add `export [variable_name]=[variable_value]` at the end of it
- save any changes you made to the `.bash_profile` file
- execute the new `.bash_profile` by either restarting the terminal window or using `source ~/.bash-profile`

If you **don't** want to use the mentioned `dotenv` library you'll have to **source** the .env file first and **export** all the variables before running your python script which uses `os.getenv`, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65694371/15923186