# "Error when trying to convert the environment variable 'DEBUG' to a Boolean value in Python"

Tags: .env

I have a problem trying to use the 'DEBUG' environment variable in my Python application. I set the value of the 'DEBUG' environment variable in my environment file as follows:

Then, in my Python code, I try to convert the value of this variable to a Boolean value as follows:

```
import os
DEBUG = bool(int(os.environ.get('DEBUG')))
```

However, an error occurs when executing this code TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType',  and I don't understand why this is happening.

My environment variable 'DEBUG' is defined in my environment file and set to "1", which I think should work. What am I doing wrong and how do I solve this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading in environment variables from an environment file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216311/reading-in-environment-variables-from-an-environment-file)