# System.get_env in dev.ex Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to get env file values in my `dev.exs` file. But they are coming as nil.

```
config :extractor, :mailgun,
  domain: System.get_env['MAILGUN_DOMAIN'],
  key: System.get_env['MAILGUN_KEY']
```

When I go to `iex` they are coming as actual values. In my app `mix.exs` I have added `dotenv` like this

```
  def application do
    [mod: {Extractor, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :tzdata, :httpoison, :dotenv, :quantum]]
  end
```

Its not specified for any env. Its just in application list.

I already tried this way as well

```
  def application do
    [mod: {Extractor, []},
     applications: app_list(Mix.env)]
  end


  defp app_list(:dev), do: [:dotenv | app_list]
  defp app_list(:test), do: [:dotenv | app_list]
  defp app_list(_), do: app_list
  defp app_list, do: [
    :phoenix,
    :phoenix_pubsub,
    :phoenix_html,
    :cowboy,
    :logger,
    :gettext,
    :phoenix_ecto,
    :postgrex,
    :tzdata,
    :httpoison,
    :dotenv,
    :quantum
  ]
```

But no luck as well.. any help?

Comment: https://github.com/avdi/dotenv_elixir has a big warning at the top of the README which (somewhat) mentions/explains this: "Elixir has an excellent configuration system and this dotenv implementation has a serious limitation in that it isn't available at compile time. ...".

Comment: An option is https://medium.com/@kkomaz/phoenix-setting-up-env-variables-6557eb1370ee  But if you read it also read comments as there is small type. https://medium.com/p/6557eb1370ee/responses/show

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use `dotenv` (as stated on their github page https://github.com/avdi/dotenv_elixir, Elixir has a very good system on its own to handle env configuration).

Try this out and tell me if it does it for you :

1. Create a simple `.env` file at the root of your project where you export your env variables :

.env

```
export MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mailgundomain.com
...
```

2. **Source it** : `source .env` before launching the server or iex.
3. Access your env variables defined in your `dev.exs` as follows :

`Application.get_env(:extractor, :mailgun)[:domain]`

And use double quotes instead of single quotes. From Elixir point of view, 'foo' and "foo" are two different things.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the warnings at https://github.com/avdi/dotenv_elixir and referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909045/111021, I came up with this in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias mix='env $([ -f .env ] && cat .env | xargs) mix'
alias iex='env $([ -f .env ] && cat .env | xargs) iex'
```

This works for common use cases `mix phoenix.server` and `iex -S mix`. If your dotenv has complicated values like quotes or spaces you may need to further tweak the commands.

---

Caveat: if you use something like `mix release` https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery you may get env vars mixed into the package.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quoted `strings` as a keys, not single quoted charlists.

```
System.get_env["LOGNAME"]
> "patnowak"

System.get_env['LOGNAME']
> nil
```