# How to pass .env variables from docker-compose to entrypoint's script?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

How can I make the bash script to see env variables set on .env and/or inside docker-compose yaml?

**.env**

```sh
VARIABLE_ENV=VALUE_ENV
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  service:
    volumes:
      - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    environment:
      - VARIABLE_YML=VALUE_YML
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "${VARIABLE_ENV}"
echo -e "${VARIABLE_YML}"
```

Comment: Once you mount in the .env file, by adding a volume, then you can [source it in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267413/shell-how-to-set-environment-variables-from-env-file) ... or load it into the compose with env_file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.env` file sets variables that are visible to Compose, in the same way as if you had `export`ed them in your containing shell, but it doesn't automatically set those in containers.  You can either tell Compose to pass through specific variables:

```yaml
environment:
  - VARIABLE_YML=VALUE_YML # explicitly set
  - VARIABLE_ENV           # from host environment or .env file
```

Or to pass through everything that is set in the `.env` file:

```yaml
environment:
  - VARIABLE_YML=VALUE_YML # as above
env_file: .env
```

The other important difference between these two forms is whether host environment variables or the `.env` file takes precedence.  If you pass through a value in `environment:` then the host environment variable wins, but if it's in `env_file:`, `.env` is always used.

```sh
VARIABLE_ENV=foo docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thanks David. `env_file: .env` worked. In fact, I must confess that I did not tested reading the values set in the YAML file, just the one inside the .env file. I assumed they worked the same way, but in fact, the ones set in the YAML are visbile to the script, while the .env have to be told to.

Comment: This isn't clear in the docker docs. Your answer should be incorporated into them for those trying to overwrite shell env vars with those in an `.env` file. Thanks!