# Create an assoiciated array based on a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I've got a file test.tmp, and the file has the following content.

```
AAA 100
BBB 200
CCC 300
```

I'd like to create an associated array to save this information, so the key value pair would be

`[AAA]=100, [BBB],200...`

the code in the following is what I tried though it didn't work:

```
declare -A index
while read line
do
     index[`echo $line | awk '{print $1}']=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`)
done < test.tmp
```

This is the code I used to check the array

```
for i in ${!index[@]}
do
        echo "index $i: ${index[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Use `read -r key value`  instead of `read line`!! Then `index[$key]="$value"`...

Comment: See how tu use `read`: [How to set environment variables from .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43267603/1765658)

Comment: HI, i've changed my code with what you suggested and used the following code to check, but the value isn't written in the array
```
for i in ${!index[@]}
do
        echo "index $i: ${index[i]}"
done
```

Comment: @TileiLiu you left out a `$` ... `${index[i]}` should be `${index[$i]}`; an alternative way to check the contents of the array: `typeset -p index` (or `declare -p index`)