# Bash - export environment variables with special characters ($)

Tags: bash

I'm parsing a file with `key=value` data and then export them as environment variables. My solution works, but not with special characters, example:

.data

```
VAR1=abc
VAR2=d#r3_P{os-!kblg1$we3d4xhshq7=mf$@6@3l^
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
  case "$key" in
    '#'*) ;;
    *)
      eval "$key=\"$value\""
      export $key
  esac
done < .data
```

`$ . ./script.sh`

Output:

```
$ echo $VAR1
abc
$ echo $VAR2
d#r3_P{os-!kblg1=mf6@3l^
```

but should be: `d#r3_P{os-!kblg1$we3d4xhshq7=mf$@6@3l^`

Comment: Try single quotes? That seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need *eval* at all, just use `declare` built-in in `bash` to create variables on-the-fly!

```
case "$key" in
  '#'*) ;;
   *)
       declare $key=$value
       export "$key"
esac
```

Answer (score 57):

Just use single quotes:

```sh
export VAR2='d#r3_P{os-!kblg1$we3d4xhshq7=mf$@6@3l^'
```

Comment: if string contain , then VAR2 will become array and whole string will be split with ,

Answer (score 18):

Just escape the $ sign with backslash \

Comment: If the data is automatically generated by some 3rd-party application and saved in the `.data` file then you might not be able to do it in an automated environment

Comment: how do you escape `&` ?

Comment: also with a backslash, here is an exmaple:

`# echo \&`
`&`

Comment: Very inefficient if you have multiple characters that will need to be passed escaped

Comment: you escape ^ in the same manner. I do not have the list of special characters that can be escaped with \ but one can empirically conjecture and verify at the command line

Answer (score 3):

I found the following script (to be sourced) helpful:

```
set -a
source <(cat development.env | \
    sed -e '/^#/d;/^\s*$/d' -e "s/'/'\\\''/g" -e "s/=\(.*\)/='\1'/g")
set +a
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66118031/339144

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change the **.data** file you have to escape the special character `$` when assigning the value to key. Change the assignment line to:

```
eval "$key=\"${value//\$/\\\$}\""
```

`${variable//A/B}` means substituting every instance of `A` to `B` in `variable`.

More useful info on bash variables [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)