# Node Js Environment Specific Variables Dev/Testing/UAT

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, node-modules

I am new to Node js, started developing the Angular application using Angular 1.2 and Node js. As of now, I have hardcoded the REST API(Java) endpoints in the node services.js. Now I want to load the base endpoint URI specific to the environment. I have tried few ways by setting a new key value for the process.env, a env file and load it. Can anyone please help me.

I have tried below approach.

Created devEnv.env file under root folder.

Added 3 key-value pairs

```
hostname = xyz
apikey = 123
devUrl = xyz/xyz/xyz.com/
```

Then in terminal, I am trying to add it to the source.

```
$ source denEnv.env
```

I am getting source not found.

Another way I have added the script in package.json file

```
{
  "start-dev": "source devEnv.env; node server.js"
}
```

In terminal I executed

```
$ npm start-dev
```

It's also failing. Can anyone please let me know what mistake I am doing and what is the correct approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are three methods known to me:

**1) .env file**

You need to install [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package using `npm install`/`yarn add` and on top of your main file (e.g. `index.js`) put `require('dotenv').config()`. That should load your variables to node.

**2) passed on a start**

If you want pass a small amount of environmental variables you can try something like this in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "start-dev": "hostname=xyz apikey=123 devUrl=xyz/xyz/xyz.com node server.js"
}
```

Advice: environmental variables should look like `HOSTNAME`, `API_KEY` or `DEV_URL`.

**3) system environmental variables**

Solution: [Set environment variables from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have tried the first approach and its working. I even tried with env2 package and working fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are most likely not being exported to the shell. To be able to source your devEnv.env script, try to modify it as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

export hostname=xyz
export apikey=123
export devUrl=xyz/xyz/xyz.com/
```

You most likely need to give it executable rights:

```
chmod +x devEnv.env
```

And then source it by running:

```
. devEnv.env
```

Another example can be found here: [Set environment variables from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file)