# Load .env environment variables when running npm task

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

Let's say we have a `.env` file with some variables specified:

```
AWS_PROFILE=hsz
ENVIRONMENT=development
```

There is also a simple `npm` task defined:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "sls deploy"
  }
}
```

But runnning `npm run deploy` ignores our `.env` definition.

It can be resolved with `better-npm-run` like:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "bnr deploy"
  },
  "betterScripts": {
    "deploy": "sls deploy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "better-npm-run": "^0.1.1",
  }
}
```

but this looks like an overhead - especially when we have 10+ tasks.

Is there a better way to always load `.env` without proxying all tasks via `better-npm-run`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A bit ugly, but you could try something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "export $(cat .env | xargs) && sls deploy"
}
```

This will export all environment variables from the `.env` file before running `sls deploy`.

There are some variations to this tehnique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909045/865038).

Not very clean but it avoids usage of an extra module.

Comment: This will crash when having commented lines in your .env file but you can fix it by replacing `cat .env | xargs` with `grep '^#' .env -v | xargs`

Answer (score 9):

You can use [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd) npm package to set environment variables loaded from .env file before executing a npm script.

1. Add package to your package.json devDependencies:

```sh
npm i env-cmd -D
```

2. Prefix your npm script with env-cmd program in package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "env-cmd sls deploy"
  }
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for Windows, unlike this one ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue while trying to syncing the DB using an external command and fixed the issue by requiring `dotenv` package which will load the variables

```
"scripts": {
"db-sync": "node --require dotenv/config ./src/sequelize/sync.js"}
```

then just call `npm run db-sync`

Answer (score 0):

Maintain and load all your environment specific configuration in project itself.

dev.js

```
module.exports = {
    "host":"dev.com"
}
```

prod.js

```
module.exports = {
    "host":"prod.com"
}
```

config.js - main file that will resolve configuration based on process.env.ENV variable.

```
const dev = require('./dev');
const prod = require('./prod');
let envObject = {};
const env = process.env.ENV || "dev";
switch(env) {
    case 'prod':
        envObject = prod;
        break;
    default:
        envObject = dev;
}
envObject['ENV'] = env;
process.env = Object.assign(process.env,envObject); // Optional if you prefer to add them into process environment otherwise `require('./config')` where you need configuration. 
module.exports = envObject;
```

index.js - node project root file call every time when project start

```
const config = require('./config');
console.log('config object => ',config.host);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "sls deploy"
  }
}
```

Running you node.js code
Prod environment `ENV=prod npm run deploy`;
Development environment - `npm run deploy`;

Default environment is set to `dev` in `./config.js`

Using this simple practice you don't need any npm module to manage your environment configurations.

Comment: Thanks, but the point is to avoid prefixing `npm run` with any env variables; also in case of running `sls deploy` - external tool - no `index.js` is loaded at all.

Comment: Or create a .npmrc file inside the project root folder and set variable there. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc#files

Answer (score 0):

// .env

```
MY_ENV_VAR: '46a69247498a030'
```

// package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "myscript1": "node myscript-cmd --cmd_name=script1",
  "myscript2": "node myscript-cmd --cmd_name=script2"
},
```

// myscript-cmd.js (placed at the root of your project directory)

```
// accessing the value of 'cmd_var' passed as a command-line argument
const args = process.argv.slice(2); 
const argMap = args.reduce((acc, arg) => {
  const [key, value] = arg.split("=");
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

const cmdVarValue = argMap["--cmd_name"];

if (cmdVarValue === "myscript1") {
  require("dotenv").config();
  const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;

  execSync(`echo hello: ${process.env.MY_ENV_VAR}`, {
    stdio: [0, 1, 2],
  });

} else if(cmdVarValue === "myscript2"){
  ...
}
```