# Setting the env using a .env file in Serverless

Tags: serverless-framework

Using the [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/), I want to be able to change the AWS region from an envrionment variable.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  region: ${env:AWS_REGION}
```

Then, `AWS_REGION` can be set to `eu-west-2`.

However, I want to have that set in a `.env` file:

```
AWS_REGION=eu-west-2
```

And then have that `.env` read by Serverless.

There are many topics about setting variables in the `serverless.yml` file, and exporting them from that file, but I want to put them into the file.

Comment: Is it feasible for your case to export those `.env` file content to a yaml file. The [docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-other-files) support referencing variables from other yaml/json files, but there is no evidence for an .env

Comment: Good question @vahdet. The reason for a .env locally is that it’s easier on CI/CD to just use envs. I have thought about a JSON or YAML file, but I would have to build it from envs on the CI/CD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box serverless doesn't parse `.env`, that part belongs to you.

I see three options for you:

1. Use the [`serverless-dotenv-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dotenv-plugin).
2. Write a script that [exports `.env` vars to your local environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909045/1748964) before you run `serverless`.
3. Run serverless in `docker-compose` which is `.env` aware -- I use this in combination with Makefile, even in a CI/CD context.

Answer (score 4):

[Serverless now supports `.env` files without the need for a plugin](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables/)

1. Add `useDotenv: true` to your `serverless.yml` file. The variable should be at the root level, same as `service: ...`
2. Add a `.env` file at the root of your project and serverless will load the variables.

Example:

```
// .env
MY_TABLE=A_TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin to write .env with serverless.yaml [serverless-export-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-export-env). so you just need to overwrite your region inside serverless yaml, and your env will be generated based on whay you've written in serverless.yaml.