# set environment variable from .txt file in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: environment-variables

I need set more than 100 environment variable from file.txt .this variable in text file is same below:

```
env=BACKTORY_AUTHENTICATION_MASTER_KEY=058f04d8ea6545sdf65sde99e49
env=BACKTORY_AUTHENTICATION_CLIENT_KEY=5a3ba2f0e4b0a24sdfsd4ffb4
env=BACKTORY_MASTER_ACCESS_TOKEN=my_token
.
.
.
```

is any way to set this variable automatically ?
and second question is : one time i set this variable manually by this way `export variable = value` one by one! but now i cant see any of them when i use `printenv`. is after restarting Ubuntu every environment variable will deleting? 
thanks.

Comment: Does the format *have* to be like that? If you make it an actual script you could `source` it.

Comment: This post may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-pair-values

Comment: @Hyphen : Thank you but my second problem still exist . what happen to past environment variable that i set?