# Parsing postgres-config.ini using shell script returns nothing, am I missing anything?

Tags: postgresql, shell, grep, sh

I have these parameter in postgres-config.ini file:

```
PGUSER=usr
PGPASSWORD=pass
PGDATABASE=myDB
PGHOST=localhost
PGPORT=5432
```

I want to parse it and connect to database using shell script (sh file). I use source and grep command like this:

```
source <( grep = postgres-config.ini )
```

However, when I tried to print the values using `echo $PGHOST` it not printing anything.

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-value-pairs/19331521 does this answer your question?

Comment: No, it still same issue (nothing printed)

Comment: did you try this idea from the Q/A above: `set -o allexport;
source conf-file;
set +o allexport`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `source` from a process substitution works fine for me from the command line:

```sh
$ cat foo.sh
PGUSER=usr
PGPASSWORD=pass
PGDATABASE=myDB
PGHOST=localhost
PGPORT=5432
$ source <(grep = foo.sh)
$ echo $PGHOST
localhost
```

Note that the shell variables aren't exported, so they won't be available in subprocesses. If you need them in subprocesses, try:

```sh
source <(sed '/=/!d;s/^/export /' foo.sh)
```

which uses `sed` to add an `export` command to lines which match `=`.

Also, where are you running the `source` from? If it is in a script, remember that the variables will disappear when the script ends and are not passed to the parent process.