# How to inject secrets from Google Secret Manager into Kubernetes Pod as environment variable?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to inject my secrets from Google Secret Manager into Kubernetes Pod as environment variable.

I need put it as environment variable to my NodeJS application can read it.

I tried the solution from [How to inject secret from Google Secret Manager into Kubernetes Pod as environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63923379/how-to-inject-secret-from-google-secret-manager-into-kubernetes-pod-as-environme) but not work for me.

Also I tried to setup a init container but it put the secrets as files into the pod.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your configuration file please to see what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this during cloud build step.

```
steps:
- name: '<secrets_to_configmap>'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['USERNAME=$$USERNAME', 'PASSWORD=$$PASSWORD']
  secretEnv: ['USERNAME', 'PASSWORD']
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET_NAME/versions/SECRET_VERSION
    env: 'PASSWORD'
  - versionName: projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET_NAME/versions/SECRET_VERSION
    env: 'USERNAME'
```

The docker image `secrets_to_configmap` will take the secrets from secrets manager and create a configmaps which pods can use.

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#:%7E:text=Secret%20Manager%20is%20a%20Google,the%20information%20from%20Secret%20Manager.)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-gcp. It's a CSI driver for mounting Secret Manager secrets.