# GitLab CI/CD: is it possible to store multiple CI/CD variables in one file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, secret-key

I'm using GitLab CI/CD, and I store the secrets variables of the process in custom CI/CD variables, as documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-cicd-variables).

It started small, and with only a few variables, using the UI to define the variables is ok. But now, my project have gone bigger, and I end with dozens of variables, multiplied by a fair number of environments. At this point, it becomes tedious to manage them in the UI:

[image]
...and so on.

What I would like to do, which in my opinion is much more manageable, is to put all variables for an environement in a single file:

```sh
API_TOKEN_VALUE=xxxx
APP_EMAIL_SENDER=xxx
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
AWS_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
...
```

And then store this single file as a unique CI/CD variable `VAR_FILE`, of type "File":
[image]

My question is, if I do this, how can I access those variables in `gitlab-ci.yml` and make them available to the jobs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `xargs` and `cat` available in your build image you could load them via

```sh
before_script:
    - export $(grep -v '^#' $VAR_FILE | xargs)
```

based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909045/3708208 (generally within this question you will find a lot of information).

Those will than be available by the name you defined in your CI Variables like `API_TOKEN_VALUE` or `APP_EMAIL_SENDER`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly! Also tried `before_script:  - set -o allexport; source $VAR_FILE; set +o allexport` from [this other answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969768/2761700), works also.

Comment: unfortunately the variables in the format specified in the question can not be masked, which is a big vulnerabilty. https://gitlab.hmm.tools/help/ci/variables/README#mask-a-custom-variable