# How to set the variables from .env file when using Django and Gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: django, gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run the tests of my Django app in Gitlab CI/CD. The process fails every time with an error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`.

I assume this is because I have not my .env file available in the repository and that file contains for example the `SECRET_KEY` -variable which is then used in the `settings.py` like this: `SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')`.

So what would be the proper way to set these variables so my tests would pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way is to add the secret in CI variable.
Then export it in target repo.

http://your/gilab/url/project/-/settings/ci_cd > Expand variables

Add a variable named SECRET_KEY, with the value, select type variable.
Then in .gitlab-ci.yml, add following in concerned job.

```
 before_script:
    # to export variable to target environment
    - export SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY  
    # to check if OK
    - env
```

When set up the variable, you might select on which environment (dev, staging, prod) if you have many env.

Comment: What if I have a .env file that contains more than 50 variables. Is there a way to export them at once without having to write them one by one like you do above?

Comment: create a ci with FILE type (ex : CI_DEPLOY_CONFIG_FILE) then use this :
before_script:
            - export $(grep -v '^#' $CI_DEPLOY_CONFIG_FILE | xargs)

Comment: like in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278742/gitlab-ci-cd-is-it-possible-to-store-multiple-ci-cd-variables-in-one-file

Answer (score 1):

Create ci-cd variables select file as type. Give your file name as key and put all your variables in values input. Like this

[gitlab ci variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/442No.png)

Then in your job, you can do something like this :

> before_script:
> - cat $env > path/where/save/envfile/inyourprojet

Comment: Works for me. With the `export SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY` in other answer I wasn't successfull.