# Run Laravel command dependent on environment variables

Tags: php, laravel, bash, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Generally speaking when wanting to see the routes locally I'd use

```
php artisan route:list
```

That worked fine when I wasn't dealing with files that use environment variables which are declared differently between my local environment and the server. Now I get

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VARIABLE_NAME in ....php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined index: VARIABLE_NAME in ....php on line 12

In particular, in the server I use

```
if (!defined('VARIABLE_NAME')) { define('VARIABLE_NAME', $_SERVER['VARIABLE_NAME']); }

$variable = env('VARIABLE_NAME') ? env('VARIABLE_NAME') : VARIABLE_NAME;
```

Basically the difference between the server and the local environment would be the following part (which locally I don't use and is where the conflict is at because there's no `$_SERVER['VARIABLE_NAME'])`)

```
if (!defined('VARIABLE_NAME')) { define('VARIABLE_NAME', $_SERVER['VARIABLE_NAME']); }
```

Tested other variations too, like

```
if (!defined('VARIABLE_NAME') or !getenv('VARIABLE_NAME')) { define('VARIABLE_NAME', $_SERVER['VARIABLE_NAME']); }
```

I could change the change the code locally and ignore the file. Yet this is a file that can change frequently, so that's not ideal.

In light of the goal (see the route list), what would be the most convenient way? By convenient I mean without having to declare the variables one in the shell or having to mantain different files for both local and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969768/5675325), before running

```
php artisan route:list
```

I'd run

```
set -o allexport
source .env
set +o allexport
```

and then was able to see the routes just fine

[image]