# Can you tell me how to pass the CONTAINER env path file during the docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Can you tell me how to pass the CONTAINER env path file during the docker run?

More likely

```
docker run -it -d --env-file=<path of env file in container> NOT THE HOST ENV PATH
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add Environment Variables using ENV command inside the Dockerfile. Or copy over a file into your image during build and set them as environment varibles  using a script

Comment: main agenda . step 1. file (.env) will be copied to dockerFile 2.during container start i want specify the path of env (inside the container) ...

Comment: If you copy the environment file into the container during build, it'll always be in the same spot. So passing the location at run-time seems odd. Why don't you set the location at build time using a ENV statement?

Answer (score 0):

`docker run -it -d --env-file=./somefile.txt` [will read from the file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) and make vars inside that file available as `ENV` in the container.

If you want to replace a file you put into the container at creation, you could [use a mount binding](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only).

`docker  run  -v /some/path/on/the/host:/path/in/the/container`

Answer (score 0):

Docker on its own doesn't know how to do this, but it's easy to write an entrypoint wrapper script that does:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# If the script was started with an `ENV_FILE` environment variable,
# read that file in.
if [ -n "$ENV_FILE" ]; then
  . "$ENV_FILE"
fi

# Run the main container CMD.
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, `COPY` this script in, and set the image's `ENTRYPOINT` to run it.  (If you already have only an `ENTRYPOINT`, change it to `CMD`; if you already have a wrapper script like this, add this fragment there.)

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array form
CMD the same main container command as before
```

The particular setup I've shown here requires the file to be a shell script fragment (it would need to `export VAR=value` for variables to be usable); other recipes like [Set environment variables from file of key/value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-value-pairs/30969768#30969768) can support a flat `VAR=value` syntax like what `docker run --env-file` would support.

Since this setup always runs the `ENTRYPOINT` and it's straightforward to override the `CMD` at the `docker run` command, you can pretty easily check that this is working by running tools like **env**(1) to dump out the environment.  This would happen as the `exec "$@"` step at the end of the file, so after your first-time setup has happened.

```sh
docker run --rm -e ENV_FILE=env.sh my-image:latest /usr/bin/env
```