# how to remove the junk data coming on script output when loading variables on a script?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I wanted to load a secret value like a password when using a script on bash. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-value-pairs/19331521) method of loading from a file rather exporting on bash profile.

I wrote this sample script to test it

```
cat -n run.sh
 1  echo $val1
 2  echo "-line1----"
 3  set -o
 4  source /tmp/jas/test.txt
 5  set +o
 6  echo $val1
 7  echo $val2
 8  echo "--line2---"
 9  echo $val2
```

Seems it is working good , but when I run the script , I see output as

```
-line1----
allexport       off
braceexpand     on
emacs           off
errexit         off
errtrace        off
functrace       off
hashall         on
histexpand      off
history         off
ignoreeof       off
interactive-comments    on
keyword         off
monitor         off
noclobber       off
noexec          off
noglob          off
nolog           off
notify          off
nounset         off
onecmd          off
physical        off
pipefail        off
posix           off
privileged      off
verbose         off
vi              off
xtrace          off
set +o allexport
set -o braceexpand
set +o emacs
set +o errexit
set +o errtrace
set +o functrace
set -o hashall
set +o histexpand
set +o history
set +o ignoreeof
set -o interactive-comments
set +o keyword
set +o monitor
set +o noclobber
set +o noexec
set +o noglob
set +o nolog
set +o notify
set +o nounset
set +o onecmd
set +o physical
set +o pipefail
set +o posix
set +o privileged
set +o verbose
set +o vi
set +o xtrace
value1
value2
--line2---
value2
```

Can someone help me with

1. what are those values or suggestions on screen ? how to ignore them when I run a script?
2. once the script is done, on command like I tried

```
$echo $val1
```

and got no result. So it seems like working and being used on script only.
But I feel this is a security issue in a different level that, one knows the path of file can read the values as they are in plane text.  Is there any better way?

Comment: That's the output of `set -o` and `set +o` – are you perhaps expecting these commands to do something such as suppressing output?

Comment: Yeah , I guess I misunderstood the usage of it. As I said, my use case was to load the variable only for that specific script . If I use .bash_profile it will available for everything under that user. Hope I made sense. 

this seems like an useful one, but the whole list of output is too much. Also I have my other questions.