# What is the best way to load environment variables in your build

Tags: npm, webpack, environment-variables, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

For a project I am working on I am setting up a BitBucket pipeline. Everything works great except for the environment vars. One of the usages of my env vars is the API_URL. I am loading the url by using `process.env.API_URL`. Locally this works great since it loads the .env file by using `dotenv-webpack`. However, in the pipeline I don't know what the best way is to load these vars. Should I add all the vars to Bitbucket and add `export API_URL=$API_URL` for every var in the pipeline file or are there better ways to load the vars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workspace, Repository, and Deployment variables is the way to go. Which one you need depends on scope you'd like these variables to cover (naming is pretty self-explanatory: some variables shouldn't change their values across your entire account; others only make sense to a particular repository; finally, some values are specific to a deployment environment).

Just define the variables in the Bitbucket UI or using API, and refer to their values from `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` or any script that you invoke from it. You don't need to add any `export` statements.
Here's a very good doc explaining the details - https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/ - and `User-defined variables` section is particularly relevant to your question.

Alternatively, if you committed your `.env` file, you can simply export its contents all at once as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-value-pairs) StackOverflow answer.

*Obviously, don't commit `.env` if it contains any sensitive values.*

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you are using to serve your application & at build stage `npm build` creates a static artefacts with env values.
So you can use nginx subfilter in case using nginx to replace the values with environment variable.

Also, you can set env as mentioned here - https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/