# Laravel Artrisan Tinker on Elastic Beanstalk env() Variables

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tinker

I am using Elastic Beanstalk for a project and was trying to execute a script via the console. When I did this, I was getting a strange error and tried to use Artisan Tinker to diagnose the problem.

When using Tinker, I found that it was unable to access the environment variables on Elastic Beanstalk and I suspect this might be related to why I was not able to execute a script manually via the console.

I found that Tinker could not access the environment variables because when I tried to dump something as simple as the environment  "APP_ENV", it would return "null" instead of "development".

Is there a way to get Tinker to have access to the Elastic Beanstalk environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to start artisan tinker with your Elastic Beanstalk variables:

```bash
set -a && source <(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | sed -e '/^#/d;/^\s*$/d' -e "s/'/'\\\''/g" -e "s/=\(.*\)/='\1'/g") && set +a && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan tinker
```

**Explaination:**

The environment variables are located in the `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env` file.

To load .env files I looked at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66118031/7116840.
This is merged into one command as following:

```bash
set -a && source <(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | sed -e '/^#/d;/^\s*$/d' -e "s/'/'\\\''/g" -e "s/=\(.*\)/='\1'/g") && set +a
```

Then to start `php artisan tinker` the following command is appended:

```bash
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan tinker
```

This loads *php* from the `/usr/bin` directory and than starts `artisan tinker` from your project directory which is located in `/var/www/html`