# Why isn't telegraf reading environmental variables?

Tags: environment-variables, telegraf

My goal is to put my telegraf config into source control. To do so, I have a repo in my user's home directory with the appropriate config file which has already been tested and proven working.

I have added the path to the new config file in the "default" environment variables file:

`/etc/default/telegraf`

like this:

```
TELEGRAF_CONFIG_PATH="/home/ubuntu/some_repo/telegraf.conf"
```

... as well as other required variables such as passwords.

However, when I attempt to run

`telegraf --test`

It says `No config file specified, and could not find one in $TELEGRAF_CONFIG_PATH` etc.

Further, if I force it by

`telegraf --test --config /home/ubuntu/some_repo/telegraf.conf`

Then the process fails because it is missing the other required variables.

Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there not also a way of specifying a config directory too (I would like to break my file down into separate input files)?
3. Perhaps as an alternative to all of this... is there not a way of specifying additional configuration files to be included from *within* the default `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` file? (I've been unable to find any mention of this in documentation).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What am I doing wrong?

See what user:group owns `/etc/default/telegraf`. This file is better used when running telegraf as a service via systemd. Additionally, if you run `env` do you see the `TELEGRAF_CONFIG_PATH` variable? What about your other variables? If not, then you probably need to source the file first.

> 2. Is there not also a way of specifying a config directory too (I would like to break my file down into separate input files)?

Yes! Take a look at all the options of telegraf with `telegraf --help` and you will find:

```s
  --config-directory <directory> directory containing additional *.conf files
```

> 3. Perhaps as an alternative to all of this... is there not a way of specifying additional configuration files to be included from within the default /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf file? (I've been unable to find any mention of this in documentation).

That is not the method I would suggest going down. Check out the config directory option above I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a LOT of trial and error, I figured everything out. For those facing similar issues, here is your shortcut to the answer:

Firstly, remember that when adding variables to the `/etc/default/telegraf` file, it must effectively be reloaded. So for example using ubuntu systemctl, that requires a restart.

You can verify that the variables have been loaded successfully using this:

$ `sudo strings /proc/<pid>/environ`

where `<pid>` is the "Main PID" from the telegraf status output

Secondly, when testing (eg `telegraf --test`) then (this is the part that is not necessarily intuitive and isn't documented) you will have to ALSO load the same environmental variables into the current user (eg: SET var=value) such that running

$ `env`

shows the same results as the previous command.

Hint: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969768/9819342) is a good method for loading the current env file directly rather than doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Add env vars to **/etc/default/telegraf** file in order to access them in telegraf.conf file.

https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md

[image: configuration screenshot]