# Calling env file in a bash file

Tags: shell, unix, psql

Need to call env file in shell script

```
PGHOST=${PGHOST-'local host'}
PGPORT=${PGPORT-5432}
PGDATABASE=${PGDATABASE-'mydb'}
PGUSER=${PGUSER-'myuser'}
PGPASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD-'pwd#0000'}
```

My shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
export MYPATH ="C/Documents/my_env.env":$MYPATH
# If psql is not available, then exit
if ! command -v psql > /dev/null ; then
  echo "This script requires psql to be installed and on your PATH. Exiting"
  exit 1
fi

RUN_PSQL="psql -X --set AUTOCOMMIT=off --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on "

${RUN_PSQL} <<SQL
select count(1) from my_table
SQL
```

When I try to run it throws error saying syntax error unexpected end of file and warning here document delimited by end of file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set environment variables from file of key/value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-value-pairs)

Comment: Do you have ms DOS line ending? If yes, use `dos2unix`

Comment: Hi Luuk, I referenced the link you shared and tried all including source command but it didn’t work . Am I missing anything here ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: @UdayasoorianCN Please [edit] your question, add what exactly you tried based on the linked question, copy&paste the resulting output and show the expected output. Explain in which way it "didn't work", unless it is obvious from the error message or from actual and expected output.

Comment: Hi Bodu, thanks for your reply . My output shows ' No such file or directoryator/test_file.sh: line 2: ./test_env.env
 warning: here-document at line 13 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `SQL
/c/Documents/test_file.sh: line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: This is the error i get when i try to execute a shell script

Comment: 1) It is pretty unclear what/where line #13 (or #18) is.  2) You get an error about `/test_file.sh`, which is possibly (???, I am guessing here!) the same file as `my_env.env` onl ine #3 of the script you did show.

Comment: Syntax error: `export MYPATH ="C/Documents/my_env.env":$MYPATH`, do not put spaces around the `=` sign.  Put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check syntax.

Comment: Hi Nic, Thanks a lot for your reply. I will do it ...Thanks