# How to use environment variables from file of key/value pairs in command? Values could have spaces

Tags: bash

I see great [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909045/4632019), but I can not adopt it to my command:

```
$ echo 'TEST="value with spaces"' > .env

$ cat .env
TEST="value with spaces"

$ env $(cat .env | xargs -d "\n" ) echo $TEST
env: with: No such file or directory

$ export $(cat .env | xargs -d "\n" ) echo $TEST
-bash: export: `spaces"': not a valid identifier
```

I can use `eval` but it spoils my environment:

```
$ eval $(cat .env | xargs -d "\n" ); echo $TEST
value with spaces

$ echo $TEST
value with spaces
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want temporary environment variables from a file without otherwise changing your execution environment, some options are:

- Use a subshell. The new environment will only apply to the commands between `( )`.

```
( source .env ; echo "$TEST" )
```

- Use a child bash process and tell it to read environment variables from the file. Other programs may have a similar way to pass in an environment, either via an environment variable or a command line option. You'll have to check their manuals.

```
BASH_ENV=.env bash -c 'echo "$TEST"'
```

Note a potential pitfall with something like:

```
TEST="thing with spaces" echo "|$TEST|" #prints ||
```

Scoped environment variables are given to the program when it executes, but variables are substituted *before* the program executes. Whatever solution you end up using, you have to ensure the environment you want is in place before you attempt to reference variables from that environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the only one solution: I should run a sub shell to not spoil environment:

```bash
$ bash -c 'eval $(cat .env | xargs -d "\n" ); echo $TEST'
value with spaces

$ echo $TEST

$
```

Still would be nice to have a solution without subshell.

**UPD**
Someone commented and quickly deleted it. I also can source that file:

```bash
$ . .env; echo $TEST
value with spaces
```