# Set environment variables from file of key/value pairs in Nu

Tags: environment-variables, nushell

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19331497/11810933) for Bash, I'd like to have a simple `.env` file or similar that I can read into the Nushell environment.  While I'll typically use this for API keys, to simply re-use the same example from that question:

```
MINIENTREGA_FECHALIMITE="2011-03-31"
MINIENTREGA_FICHEROS="informe.txt programa.c"
MINIENTREGA_DESTINO="./destino/entrega-prac1"
```

Of course, Nushell is not POSIX, so none of those answers will work.

The Nushell syntax for setting an environment variable is:

```
$env.foo = "value"
```

And while it's possible to `source-env` a file that modifies the environment, that file needs to be a valid Nu script, which the `.env` is not.

I'd like to keep the structure of the file "standard" so that it can be used with other shells and tools, but how can I use it to set environment variables in Nushell?

Answer (score 3):

Took me a few tries to get right, so throwing this out in case it helps others (and so I can find it easily in the future).  I found two ways to do this in Nushell.

##### Treat as a TOML file

The file format as it stands is a valid TOML file, and Nushell has built in support for TOML as structured data.  As a result, we can easily read it with:

```
> open .env | from toml

╭─────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────╮
│ MINIENTREGA_DESTINO     │ ./destino/entrega-prac1 │
│ MINIENTREGA_FECHALIMITE │ 2011-03-31              │
│ MINIENTREGA_FICHEROS    │ informe.txt programa.c  │
╰─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────╯
```

And from there, since the result is a Nushell record, `load-env` can be used to load it into the environment:

```
> open .eenv | from toml | load-env
> echo $env.MINIENTREGA_FECHALIMITE
2011-03-31
```

TOML also supports comments, so you can have a valid (Bash) commented file as well and `from toml` will ignore them.

The caveats are that the file *must* be valid TOML, including quotes.

##### Or load it through Bash first

Fair warning:  I know this seems really hacky, but I've been using this method successfully for a few years now on the Fish shell (also not POSIX) to process Bash scripts, and it also works for this modified use-case on Nushell.

With credit to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969768/11810933) on the Bash version of this question:

```
exec bash -lic "set -o allexport && source ~.env && set +o allexport; exec nu"
```

This:

- `exec`s Bash (replacing the current Nushell)
- Sets the Bash option to export all variables to the environment
- `source`s the .env
- Resets the option
- `exec`s Nushell, replacing the previous Bash

Since the variables were exported from Bash, they'll now be available in Nu.

- Pro's:  This works for any Bash/POSIX script/format.
- Con's:  Slower, since it launches both shells and processes the startup files on both.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`parse`](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/parse.html#frontmatter-title-for-strings) you can achieve very nice results with only nushell commands.

This function allows opening a `.env` file with quotes and without. It also handles comments.

```
def "from env" []: string -> record {
  lines 
    | split column '#' 
    | get column1 
    | filter {($in | str length) > 0} 
    | parse "{key}={value}"
    | update value {str trim -c '"'}
    | transpose -r -d
}
```

Comment handling is done by splitting on `#` and getting the first element, then it remove any empty lines. After that it uses the `parse` mentioned earlier to parse the lines. Then it trims quotes if any exists. Finally using `tranpose -r -d` will transpoe the table into an object.

Then you can do something like `open .env | load-env`.

**Edit**: This is now also part of the [nu_scripts repo](https://github.com/nushell/nu_scripts), you can find it [here](https://github.com/nushell/nu_scripts/blob/main/modules/formats/from-env.nu).