# Locust : Not able to use the config value from env file

Tags: python, environment-variables, api-key

I am trying to run a locust test but I am not able to use the .env file values

.env file contains
"Value": diuqriqjqj

In the locust.py I have added

```
apiKey = os.environ.get("VALUE", "")
class Api(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)

    @task
    def test_api(self):
        self.client.get(
            f"/api/test/apiKey={apiKey}"
        )
```

I run the locust using

```
if test -f .env; then locust -f locust.py; fi
```

and receive connection errors. If I hardcode the apiKey value all works fine.

Comment: Why would it load things from a .env file? A quick google makes me think that is a node thing?

Comment: @Cyberwiz that is where my api key is present. How can I provide the env variables if I dont want to hard code them. Thanks

Comment: If your env file is a bash script, do `source .env`, if it is just ENV_VAR=value, maybe try `export $(cat .env | xargs)`

Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-value-pairs?rq=2

Just to be clear: `if test -f .env` just checks if the file exists, it doesnt load anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ifneq (,$(wildcard ./.env))
    include .env
    export
endif
```

```
        env VALUE =$(VALUE) locust -f locust.py
```